# Preg_Match PHP Script not working

Tags: php, regex

I have been referring to the PHP Manual and other sites to build this but cannot seem to get it working even though I have checked the source of the site that contains a link to externally hosted jquery file by Google so a match should be found.

I did check the regex to make sure it correctly picks up script links within the HTML but it just does not want to match it with the $sign (Signatures) that I am hoping it would match.

```
$regex = "/<script.+src=\"(.+)\"><\/script>/i";
$site = file_get_contents("http://phpcodechecker.com/");
$sign = 'jquery';
$sign = 'jQuery v2.1.3';

if (preg_match($regex, $site, $sign)) {
    echo 'A match was found.';
} else {
    echo 'A match was not found. boo boo';
}
```

What am i doing wrong could you please advise? Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: Other than the fact that HTML **should not** be processed through regular expressions, according to the [API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), the expression will be applied to the following text: `file_get_contents("http://phpcodechecker.com/")`, which does not match the pattern provided.

Comment: Note the regex is not correctly declared, you need to remove the `"`s and add `[^<]*` to allow contents inside the tag: `$regex = '/<script\b.*\bsrc="(.*?)"[^<]*>[^<]*<\/script>/i';`. Then there is a problem with `file_get_contents`, but it has already been described. Also, `$sign` must be an array `&$matches` and you have it declared as a string. Look at the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) syntax.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks it's working and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$site = 'file_get_contents("http://phpcodechecker.com/")';
```

Should be:

```
$site = file_get_contents("http://phpcodechecker.com/");
```

You were storing the string `'file_get_contents("http://phpcodechecker.com/")'`, instead of actually running `file_get_contents`.

Comment: woops, silly mistake but corrected although still not getting a match :(

Comment: Thanks all sorted :) silly mistake storing them as strings in the variable instead of allowing them to execute the variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DOMDocument to parse HTML. Here is how you can easily get what you need together with DOMXpath:

```
$html = <<YOUR_HTML>>;
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$scripts = $xpath->query('//script[@src]');

foreach($scripts as $script) { 
   echo $script->getAttribute('src') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/KRjDTM)

Note the regex is not correctly declared, you need to remove the `"`s and add `[^<]*` to allow contents inside the tag: `$regex = '/<script\b.*\bsrc="(.*?)"[^<]*>[^<]*<\/script>/i';` could work perhaps, but regex is not the right tool here. Then, there was a problem with `file_get_contents` (no quotes were necessary). Also, `$sign` must be an array `&$matches` and you have it declared as a string. Look at the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) syntax.